# I have data in columns and would like to convert it to rows. Specificall Manufacturer and Manufacturer PN in columns to rows

Tags: rows

I have data in columns and would like to convert to rows like below. Specifically I have Manufacture and Manufacture PN and alternates the I want to convert to rows.

Columns
527510 data 1   data 1.1  data 2   data 2.1
527520 data 1   data 1.1  data 2   data 2.1 data 3   data 3.1

Convert to rows
527510  data 1   data 1.1
527510  data 2   data 2.1
527520  data 1   data 1.1
527520  data 2   data 2.1
527520  data 3   data 3.1

Much appreciated 
T. Miller

Comment: 527510 1 R1 Resistor 1k Data 1 Data 1.1 Data 2 Data 2.1
527520 1 R2 Resistor 2k Data 1 Data 1.1 Data 2 Data 2.1

Comment: Material 1     Manuf1 Manuf PN1